# Multiple mouse pointers?

Tags: python, user-interface, mouse, multi-user

Is there a way to accept input from more than one mouse separately? I'm interested in making a multi-user application and I thought it would be great if I could have 2 or more users holding wireless mice each interacting with the app individually with a separate mouse arrow.

Is this something I should try to farm out to some other application/driver/os_magic? or is there a library I can use to accomplish this? Language isn't a *HUGE* deal, but C, C++, and Python are preferrable.

Thanks :)

edit:

Found this multi-pointer toolkit for linux (it's actually a multi-pointer x server):
http://wearables.unisa.edu.au/mpx/

Comment: Since you have selected your preferred answer, which actually does not answer the question, please publish what you will find about it.

Comment: of course! the multipoint sdk does actually let you use multiple mice with multiple pointers though ;)

Comment: Incidentally MPX will be built-in on upcoming x.org releases. It'll take a while before all the toolkits and apps are totally smooth with it though...

Comment: @bobinice very nice... looking forward to the X integration - maybe this will lead to multi-touch apps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try the [Microsoft Windows MultiPoint Software Development Kit 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F851122A-4925-4788-BC39-409644CE0F9B&displaylang=en)

or the new
[Microsoft Windows MultiPoint Software Development Kit 1.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0eb18c26-5e02-4c90-ae46-06662818f817&displaylang=en)

and the main [Microsoft Multipoint](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/) site

Comment: This link is broken - can someone with sufficient rep fix it?

Comment: it works fine for me now.. so either someone fixed it or it was just temporary.

Comment: Note that the MultiPoint SDK only works with apps based on WinForms or WPF, since its Initialize method requires a System.Windows.Window.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  I know of at least one program that does this, [KidPad](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/kiddesign/introduction.shtml).  I think it's written in Java and was developed by [Juan Pablo Hourcade](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~hourcade/), now at the University of Iowa.  You'd have to ask him how it was implemented.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/pymultimouse/ is a library using windows raw input, it worked in a test with 2 mice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DirectInput with C/C++ (there's probably also bindings in other languages).  You use [`IDirectInput8::EnumDevices()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205950(VS.85).aspx) (using DX8; same function, different interface in other versions of DirectX) to get a list of all attached devices.  Then, you create the devices and poll them [`IDirectInputDevice8::Poll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205975(VS.85).aspx).  This should almost definitely work with any number of mice, keyboards, and other input devices.  MSDN has really good documentation on this.

Comment: This will not work on Windows XP, you should use RawInput instead. See here: http://jstookey.com/arcade/rawmouse/

Answer (score 1):

I have this vague feeling that BeOS used to let one pair a mouse and keyboard and have separate active windows and inputs.  Wow... that was a long time ago.  I thought that it would be very interesting for "paired" programming.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here (avoid the JNI stuff): [How can I handle multiple mouse inputs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262125/java-multiple-mouse-inputs#263886)