# NullPointerException when opening HID Device using Java HID API (Managing Inputs from Multiple Keyboards)

Tags: java, keyboard, usb, keyboard-events, hid

This question is a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709776/is-there-a-java-c-library-which-allows-identify-multiple-keyboards) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508760/java-separate-input-of-two-separate-keyboards/21109989#21109989) thread. But since none of them have provided a clear solution for my problem, I'm asking it again.

My required task is to connect 2 Keyboards via USB and then manage the inputs of each Keyboard separately through a Java Application. This requirement has been answered into some progress in the [first thread I have mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709776/is-there-a-java-c-library-which-allows-identify-multiple-keyboards) by @nan but his solution did not work accurately for me. You can find his blog post on his solution for this [here](http://nanlee.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/manykeyboard-using-java-hid-api-to-handle-multiple-keyboard-input/#comment-67). He has done the solution using the [java-hid-api](https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/) and it seems accurate and working.

However the point I am stuck in it is at opening the HID Device. When I try to open the Device using the `HIDManager` using either the `openByPath()` or the `openById()` methods it returns only null and therefore it throws the `NullPointerException`. it is the same when I try it using the `open()` method of `HIDDeviceInfo`. [this issue is listed](https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/) in the java-hid-api page too but so far no one seems to have provided a working solution.

The OS I'm working on is Windows 7 32-bit

Here are all the 3 attempts I've made to open the HID Device

1. `HIDDevice hidDevice = HIDManager.getInstance().openByPath(hidDeviceInfo.getPath());`
2. `HIDDevice hidDevice = HIDManager.getInstance().openById(hidDeviceInfo.getVendor_id(), hidDeviceInfo.getProduct_id(), hidDeviceInfo.getSerial_number());`
3. `HIDDevice hidDevice = hidDeviceInfo.open();`

Has anyone been able to get through this problem? If so your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

**Update 1:** I just found out that this task could be accomplished with [JInput](http://java.net/projects/jinput), according to the answer provided by @paul-whelan in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262830/3127619). I am going to try it now but I'm stating here first seeking for any confirmation or a guide on how to do it if anyone already knows and have accomplished it.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: This seems to be a Windows-Issue according to the Issue-Tracker of both the C/C++ HID API and the Java Wrapper for the HID API. There is an unofficial patch for the C/C++ Implementation which solves this problem (at least it worked for me): http://angryelectron.com/javahidapi-nihardwareservice/
One can then rebuild the Java Wrapper with the patched Version (or you can directly Download the *.jar from the website above)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you do to initialize the library:

```
ClassPathLibraryLoader.loadNativeHIDLibrary();
HIDManager hm=HIDManager.getInstance();
```

Then you can read the devices etc:

```
HIDDeviceInfo[] dvl = hm.listDevices();
for (HIDDeviceInfo dv:dvl){
    System.out.println(dv.getManufacturer_string());        
}
```