# How to handle/decide the Text Field which a Key Char is being typed into upon its speed between KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyevent, hid

My problem is explained in the following scenario

There are 2 `JTextField` objects. Let's give them variable names as `jTextField1` and `jTextField2`. And the current focus owner is `jTextField2`. And the User and/or a Device is firing key inputs into the program. But according to the speed of each key being pressed and released the program should decide which text field the key char of that key input should be entered into. For an example, if the difference between `KEY_PRESSED` and `KEY_RELEASED` is less than or equal to 50 milliseconds, the Key Char should be typed into `jTextField1` and never into `jTextField2` but **while the Focus is still owned by `jTextField2` and unchanged**. If the difference between the events are greater than 50 milliseconds, the text will be typed into its current Focus Owner which is `jTextField2` (Or it may be any other object too according to what the User has the Focus at the moment.). So if there were 2 simultaneous activities happening, for an example a user is typing keys in a speed of greater than 50 milliseconds per key typing, and another device like a Barcode Scanner is firing Key Events in a speed less than 50 milliseconds, both of these inputs should be entered or typed into those different text fields separately according to their typing speeds while the focus owner is always at the object which the user is interacting with.

Here is the current code I have written which works well but with the problem that when keys are pressed in a speed less than 50 milliseconds per key, it sets at `jTextField1` but it also gets typed at `jTextField2`.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
        millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            enter1 = true;
        }
    } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - millis) <= 10) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                enter2 = true;
            } else {
                barcodeStringBuilder.append(e.getKeyChar());
            }

            if (enter1 && enter2) {
                compo = getFocusOwner();
                jTextField1.setText(barcodePool.toString());
                barcodeStringBuilder.setLength(0);
                compo.requestFocus();
            }
            enter1 = false;
            enter2 = false;
        } else {
        }
    } else if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

The previous attempt I made to accomplish this task was trying to handle the input of the two devices which are a Keyboard and a Barcode Scanner separately using the Java HID API which also was unsuccessful. You can find my question thread on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110930/nullpointerexception-when-opening-hid-device-using-java-hid-api-managing-inputs). And then I made it into this option which so far seems to be a good option.

So, does anyone know an effective way to accomplish my task as I have described above?

Thank you! And your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would not give either JTextFields focus, would not use a KeyEventDispatcher, but would instead try to use Key Bindings, and then based on the timing, append the text into the appropriate text field. This would prevent focus issues sending the text to two text fields.

Comment: my view is DocumentListener for mirroring, delay for KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED came from, is exclusively settings in Native OS  and is required to consume(again my view)