# Intercept and transform mouse input data (Mac OS)

Tags: c++, macos, filtering, hook, mouse

I am trying to apply a filter on the input signal of a computer mouse (on Mac OS). I would like to be able to intercept mouse inputs before they reach the operating system of Mac OS that implements them.

I have tried using the pynput library but the cursor seems to teleport (both the mouse input and the filter concurrently modify the position of the cursor).

I have seen on this forum a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006330/global-mouse-hook-simulate-mouse-inputs/9318292#9318292)) but the solution (a library written by someone) was supported only on Windows. I was thus wondering if there exists a library adapted to Mac OS or if there is another way to solve the issue.

To give some context, the aim of this project is to help someone with hand tremors and facilitate their use of the computer mouse.

Comment: Good luck with this.  Apple will fight you all the way.