# How to detect active USB mouse using mousekeyhook

Tags: c#

Is there a way using this library to detect which mouse is currently active? i.e the coordinates being reported are coming from which specific mouse if there is more than one mouse connected?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about MouseKeyHook but it seems a question with a similar goal exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361073/vc-multiple-mouse)

Comment: By default, if multiple mice are connected, the answer is "all of them". They'll all be supplying deltas which will all be applied to update the single cursor's position. Mice don't report a position, they just report in which directions and by how much they've moved recently.